# why does new Integer(i).hashCode() return i?

Tags: java, hashcode

I want to know why `new Integer(i).hashCode()` or `new Long(i).hashCode()` returns `i` but when `hashCode()` is invoked by some other object say `new Double(345).hashCode()`, it returns a random number. Why?

Comment: Read about `hashCode`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()

Comment: It doesn't work that way with `Long`. Try with `i = 2147483648l`

Comment: If you read the source code for those methods, it should be obvious why they cannot be the same.

Comment: I doubt that `Double.hashCode()` actually returns a random number.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Sorry. Im wrong about Double.hashCode() returning a random number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `int` value of an `Integer` perfectly satisfies and fully complies with the general contract of [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

**In short:**

The hash codes for 2 objects **must** be the same if `equals()` returns `true` and *should* be (but not required) different if `equals()` returns `false`. Also by the declaration of `Object.hashCode()` it must be an `int`. Ideally the hash code should depend on all the data that is hashed.

**Hash code of `Long`**

`Long` has to map 8 bytes to 4 bytes (size of an `int`). Current implementation of `Long.hashCode()` will only return `i` if it fits into an `int`, else it will be XOR'ed with the upper 32 bits (4 bytes):

```
return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
```

**Hash code of `Double`**

Obviously the `double` value of a `Double` does not qualify for this. `Double` also has to map 8 bytes to 4 bytes.

`Double.hashCode()` will return a seemingly random value because floating point numbers (`float` and `double`) are not stored "nicely" (e.g. 2's complement like `int` or `long`) in the bytes that are reserved for them but using  [IEEE 754 binary floating point standard](http://754r.ucbtest.org/standards/754xml.html) and so mapping those 8 bytes to 4 (this is exactly what the implementation does) will not be a meaningful number as an `int` which uses 2's complement representation.

```
long bits = doubleToLongBits(value);
return (int)(bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
```

Answer (score 7):

A value of an integer is a good enough hash because it is just as unique as the unique integer number itself.

A double has to be hashed in some different manner because the hash here has to be an integer.

Comment: so the hash always has to be integer?

Answer (score 3):

Becase the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.hashCode%28%29) say it:

```
Returns a hash code for this Integer. 

Returns:a hash code value for this object, equal to the primitive int value represented by this Integer object.

707
708     public int hashCode() {
709         return value;
710     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Different types in Java compute hash codes in different ways, non of them is random. In the case of Long Integer and Double the hashcode *is the value* except in the case of Double where it is converted to int

Answer (score 1):

This is because `hashcode()` method of `Integer` class returns value as hashcode.

```
 Returns a hash code for this <code>Integer</code>.

 @return  a hash code value for this object, equal to the 
          primitive <code>int</code> value represented by this 
          <code>Integer</code> object. 

public int hashCode() {
return value;
}
```

While `hashcode()` method of `Double` class performs some operation and returns hashcode.

```
    Returns a hash code for this Double object. The result is the exclusive OR 
    of the two halves of the long integer bit representation, exactly as produced by
    the  method  {@link #doubleToLongBits(double)}, of the primitive double value 
    represented by this Double object. That is, the hash code is the value of the
    expression:

        public int hashCode() {
        long bits = doubleToLongBits(value);
        return (int)(bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer` class "boxes" a primitive `int` value, but it has an object reference of its own.  If `Object.equals()` states that two equal objects `A` and `B` must both exhibit the same `Object.hashCode()`, it makes sense that such hash code be the former `int` value.

As for `Double`, its value might change between systems, which is why it makes sense to rely on a different mechanism to provide a hash code.